# using Qt objects with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr

I'm trying to update a small utility application to a more modern C++ fashion, but I'm having problems using some Qt objects with std::shared_ptr, especially those that receive some other QWidget as a constructor argument.

For example:

```
private:
    std::shared_ptr<QWidget> centralwidget;
    std::shared_ptr<QVBoxLayout> verticalLayout;

public:
    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow) // this pointer is a .get() from a shared_ptr
    {
        centralwidget = std::make_shared<QWidget>(new QWidget(MainWindow)); // compiles fine
        verticalLayout = std::make_shared<QVBoxLayout>(new QVBoxLayout(centralwidget.get())); // does not compile
    }
```

The compile error is:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'QVBoxLayout::QVBoxLayout(QWidget *)' : cannot
>   convert parameter 1 from 'QVBoxLayout *' to 'QWidget *'   e:\microsoft
>   visual studio 11.0\vc\include\memory  855

I cant seem to understand this error, I'm not converting anything, I'm just trying to create a QVBoxLayout object and passing a QWidget as its parent (like i would do with raw pointers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments to `std::make_shared` are passed to the constructor of the class you're instantiating. So basically what you are doing is equivalent to:

```
new QVBoxLayout(new QVBoxLayout(centralwidget.get()))
```

I think what you are trying to do is :

```
centralwidget = std::make_shared<QWidget>(MainWindow);
verticalLayout = std::make_shared<QVBoxLayout>(centralwidget.get());
```

Have a look at the documentation of `std::make_shared` (for example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410595.aspx)). The whole point of this function is to allocate the reference count near the object instance in memory, so you have to let it do the allocation for you.

Comment: thank you so much this was starting to give me a headache. so when Herb Sutter says there's not a single "new" keyword on modern c++ he wasn't kidding :p once again thanks, the utility is working and 0 memory leaks :)

Comment: Please don't skip the answer of @Frédéric Terrazzoni below for a commentary about the use of smart pointer with Qt.

Answer (score 16):

In general, I try to avoid using shared_ptr for Qt GUI objects, since Qt already provides its own memory management mechanism. Each QObject possibly has a parent, and when this parent dies he deletes all of its children. A shared_pointer is not required here and doesn't give you any added value: you could perfectly use a raw pointer without creating a memory leak.

Generally speaking, if the QObject's parent dies before the last shared_ptr instance is deleted, you'll quickly get into troubles since the object will be deleted a second time when the last shared_ptr will be destroyed. That's not the case here, but be careful :)

Comment: thanks. actually just a few minutes ago when i was testing everything more thoroughly it did start crashing on a few cases. debug said: "memory violation accessing object destructor" so yeah i think that is the case, so i just returned to my old implementation (with raw pointers) using the Qt object manager. oh well, at least it was a good exercise i suppose :) thanks again.

Comment: Want to add one more issue with std::shared_ptr<QObject>: destroying QObject in a thread different that QThread dispatching events to this particular instance is not safe. You need to play a tricky game with custom deleter calling deleteLater and try to avoid shared pointers outliving the thread object belongs to.

Comment: I can't stress enough the second paragraph of this answer. Mixing `std::shared_ptr<QObject>` and Qt-ish parent-child ownership mechanism is *really* dangerous! It leads to crashes which you exactly described. I would like to warn everybody against holding objects derived from `QObjects` in `std::shared_ptr`. This is safe only if you are sure that the `QObject` does not have and will never have a parent or that the shared pointer is destroyed before the parent, but it is very difficult to enforce especially in a large codebase. And it is impossible for `QWidgets` which always have parents.

Comment: @V.K. can't you still do `std::shared_ptr<QObject>(new myQObj(parent), [](auto) {})`? That is, use a nop deleter?